# Can connect to localhost:8443 - Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

Im trying to run Apache NiFi on my laptop. I can start the run-nifi.bat
But when I try to access http://localhost:8443/. I got an error in chrome "site can't be reached"

On the same laptop, I'm accessing different NiFi instances running on AWS. With different ports (Production).

System: Windows10

Please help to connect

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the port is not already being used by another process when nifi is not running? On windows U can use the command 'netstat -a'.
It might be that the process fails silently.

If another port is already using it, you could try changing the port in 'conf/nifi.properties' (do remember to go to that port then).

If that doesn't work also check 'nifi-bootstrap.log' & 'nifi-app.log' for any errors logged.

In the second file U might also find lines such as:

```
2018-03-22 12:46:05,076 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
2018-03-22 12:46:05,076 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer http://<hostname>:9090/nifi
2018-03-22 12:46:05,083 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
2018-03-22 12:46:05,083 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 99393967121 nanoseconds (99 seconds).
```

There may be multiple URLs listed.
Once you see above line telling you NiFi is available at following URL, then you can try to access it there.

Comment: in nifi-app.log I have the following error.

Comment: 2021-11-24 08:48:04,921 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4ec616d6
Got this error

Comment: I see a possible solution here: https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@nifi.apache.org/msg122732.html

Comment: Now I can reach the server. But got an error "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: Can you append the code that is supposed to send data to the client on your question? It might be that you're not actually sending any value.

Comment: I couldn't get what you meant. Could you please tell me where to locate it?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I can't. Sorry. I'm thinking you have something misconfigured or are not actually writing data out to the page you are trying to access.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks a lot for supporting me. Will post here once I found the solution

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you find it soon! I'm wondering though why nobody else is jumping on the wagon here too...